# Implicit conversion from Foo<TSubClass> to Bar<InterfaceOfTSubClass>

Tags: c#, .net

(or `Bar<TSuperClass>`)

I have a situation like so:

```
class Foo<TOther, TFoo> 
{ 
    static implicit operator Foo<TOther, TFoo>(Bar<TFoo> bar) { }
}
class Bar<TBar> { }
```

And I run into issues when I want to do something like this:

```
public static Foo<int, IEnumerable<string>> Example() {
    return new Bar<List<string>>();
}
```

This will throw a type error presumably because I can't define that in the
implicit conversion from Bar to Foo, TBar implements TFoo.

I can of course pull the logic out into a method on Bar to explicitly convert
to Foo and add the constraints there, but in my actual use case I have multiple
generic type params for Foo and only one maps to Bar so I would have to
explicitly specify those other type params when calling that method.

I could also specify an `IFoo<out TFoo>` to make it covariant, but the logic
that Foo implements is not (easily) describable in an interface.

Is such a constraint possible in an implicit operator?

Comment: Could you convert the `Bar<List<string>>` to a `Bar<IEnumerable<string>>` first.

Comment: It can't be done implicitly, because classes can't be variant and doing it explicitly would negate the benefits of implicit conversion.

Comment: Obligatory 'could they both compy to an interface instead?' suggestion ;)

Comment: @Davesoft I don't believe the logic can be described without type classes, or at least not without a lot of confusing boilerplate.